# Why while loop does not showing result after first iteration inside while loop?

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm trying to fetch the comments inside the while loop by `newsfeed_id`, but it does not showing any result after first iteration. I `print_r` dynamically generated query its working fine but result does not showing.

```
    $NewsfeedRes = array();
    $Newsfeed = "select * from `ws_newsfeed` where `nf_status` = 1";
    $NewsfeedQuery = mysqli_query($this->connection,$Newsfeed);
    while($rowNews = mysqli_fetch_assoc($NewsfeedQuery)){
            $NewsfeedRes[] = $rowNews;
            $PushComment = "SELECT cmt.`cmt_id`,cmt.`cmt_comment`,cmt.`date_added`,
                            us.`u_username`,us.`u_image` 
                            FROM `ws_comments` AS cmt 
                            LEFT JOIN `ws_user` AS us ON cmt.`u_id`=us.`u_id` 
                            WHERE cmt.`cmt_target_id` = ".$rowNews['nf_id']." 
                            AND cmt.`cmt_table_name`='ws_newsfeed'";
            //echo $PushComment; This giving me correct query
            $PushCommentQuery = mysqli_query($this->connection,$PushComment);
            while($rowPComment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($PushCommentQuery)){
                $NewsfeedRes['comments'] = $rowPComment;
            }
    }
    $output = array(

        'NewsfeedRes' => $NewsfeedRes,
    );
    echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Can any one guide me where I'm wrong that i can fix the issue. I will appreciate. Thanks

Comment: `$newid = $rowNews['nf_id'];` and use `'$newsid'` in the statement.

Comment: @MawiaHL I tried still showing only one record

Comment: Suppose nf_status =1 contains many rows. You don't need `$NewsfeedRes[] = $rowNews;` And select `cmt.cmt_comment as comments`.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you loop through your fetch comment loop you are resetting the the value of $NewsfeedRes['comments']. You need to push $rowPComment into an array.

If you want $rowNews and comment to be in the same array try:

```
 while($rowNews = mysqli_fetch_assoc($NewsfeedQuery)){
        $PushComment = "SELECT cmt.`cmt_id`,cmt.`cmt_comment`,cmt.`date_added`,us.`u_username`,us.`u_image` FROM `ws_comments` AS cmt LEFT JOIN `ws_user` AS us ON cmt.`u_id`=us.`u_id` WHERE cmt.`cmt_target_id` = ".$rowNews['nf_id']." AND cmt.`cmt_table_name`='ws_newsfeed'";
        //echo $PushComment; This giving me correct query
        $PushCommentQuery = mysqli_query($this->connection,$PushComment);
        while($rowPComment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($PushCommentQuery)){
            $rowNews['comments'][] = $rowPComment;
        }
        $NewsfeedRes[] = $rowNews;
}
```

If you want a seperate array for comments and news feed try:

```
    while($rowNews = mysqli_fetch_assoc($NewsfeedQuery)){
        $NewsfeedRes["newsfeed"][] = $rowNews;
        $PushComment = "SELECT cmt.`cmt_id`,cmt.`cmt_comment`,cmt.`date_added`,us.`u_username`,us.`u_image` FROM `ws_comments` AS cmt LEFT JOIN `ws_user` AS us ON cmt.`u_id`=us.`u_id` WHERE cmt.`cmt_target_id` = ".$rowNews['nf_id']." AND cmt.`cmt_table_name`='ws_newsfeed'";
        //echo $PushComment; This giving me correct query
        $PushCommentQuery = mysqli_query($this->connection,$PushComment);
        while($rowPComment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($PushCommentQuery)){
            $NewsfeedRes['comments'][] = $rowPComment;
        }

}
```